# TSQL - Multiple Values in INSERT (because of joins)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Im trying to insert a data from one database to another. This is what i have so far, on the select side:

```
USE [db2]
SELECT
    sP.pers_FirstName
    ,sp.pers_LastName
    ,sPH.Phon_Number
    ,CASE WHEN LEFT(sPH.Phon_Number, 2) = '04' THEN sPH.Phon_number ELSE NULL END
    ,CASE WHEN sp.pers_gender = 1 THEN 'M' WHEN sp.pers_gender = 2 THEN 'F' ELSE 'U' END
    ,CASE 
        WHEN sP.pers_salutation = '10'      THEN 8
        WHEN sp.pers_salutation = '6'       THEN 2
        WHEN sp.pers_salutation = '7'       THEN 1
        WHEN sp.pers_salutation = '8'       THEN 4
        WHEN sp.pers_salutation = '9'       THEN 5
        WHEN sp.pers_salutation = 'APROF'   THEN 6
        WHEN sp.pers_salutation = 'Ms.'     THEN 4
        WHEN sp.pers_salutation = 'PROF'    THEN 6
    END
    ,sp.pers_dob
    ,sp.pers_CreatedDate
    ,sp.pers_UpdatedDate
    ,'Candidate'
    ,1
    ,e.Emai_EmailAddress
    ,sP.pers_personID
FROM [db1].dbo.person sP 
LEFT JOIN [db1].dbo.PhoneLink sPL ON sp.pers_personID = sPL.PLink_recordID
LEFT JOIN [db1].dbo.Phone sPH ON sPL.PLink_PhoneId = sPH.Phon_PhoneID
LEFT JOIN [db1].dbo.EmailLink eL ON sP.pers_personID = eL.ELink_RecordID
LEFT JOIN [db1].dbo.Email e ON eL.Elink_EmailID = e.Emai_EmailID
WHERE
    (
        sP.pers_employedby NOT IN (
            'Aspen'
            ,'ACH'
            )
        )
    OR 
        (
        sP.pers_employedby IN (
            'Aspen'
            ,'ACH'
            )
        AND sP.pers_personID NOT IN ( 
            SELECT c.oppo_PrimaryPersonID FROM [SageCRM].dbo.Opportunity c
            WHERE (c.oppo_contractcompleted <= '2016-01-01' OR c.oppo_contractterminated <= '2016-01-01')  and c.Oppo_Deleted is null)
    AND
        sp.pers_isanemployee != 'ECHO'
        AND sP.pers_personID IN (
            SELECT c.oppo_PrimaryPersonID FROM [SageCRM].dbo.Opportunity c
            WHERE c.oppo_Status != 'In Progress' OR c.oppo_Status = 'Completed')
        AND sP.pers_dod IS NULL
        AND sP.pers_FirstName NOT LIKE '%test%'
        AND sP.pers_LastName NOT LIKE '%test%'
        AND sp.pers_isanemployee != 'SalesContact'
)
```

Due to the fact that each person record can have multiple phone numbers linked to them, i end up with multiple records for each person, which obviously wont work as i will end up with duplicates when i actually insert the data.

The problem is, that i need to have all of the phone numbers for each record, just displayed in a different field (home phone, work phone, mobile phone).

Any Ideas, other than doing this in a separate insert statement for each phone / email link?

-------- EDIT: -----------------------------------------------------------------

Ok so, my bad for not giving you enough information. Both of your answers were good answers so thanks for that (@Horaciux, @John Wu).

However, there is no phoneType column, just a phone number. That being said, since every mobile starts with 04 and every home phone with anything else, i can pretty easily distinguish between the two phone types.

There are duplicates in the phone table though, so i will have to delete these, most likely via CTE, shouldn't be too hard.

So, i will end up with something like this for the two phone numbers:

```
SELECT (phon_number FROM phone p INNER JOIN PhoneLink p1 on p1.PhoneLinkID = p.PhoneLink WHERE LEFT(p.Phon_Number, 2) = '04') 
SELECT (phon_number FROM phone p INNER JOIN PhoneLink p1 on p1.PhoneLinkID = p.PhoneLink WHERE LEFT(p.Phon_Number, 2) != '04')
```

My duplicate removal will be something like this:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT phon_linkID, phon_phonNumber, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY phon_phonNumber ORDER BY phon_linkID) AS RN
    FROM phone
)
DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RN<>1
```

Comment: How do you classify a list of phone numbers into different fields (home phone / work phone..)?

Comment: Add table structure to your post. Ther is possible another way, if you care about performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two easy steps.

1. Get rid of the joins to the phone number table.
2. Lookup the phone numbers per record by using a subquery in the select clause, one for each type of phone.  Example

   ```
   SELECT sP.pers_FirstName,
          sP.pers_LastName,
          (SELECT Phon_Number FROM Phone p JOIN PhoneLink pl ON pl.PhoneLinkID = p.PhoneLinkID WHERE pl.Person_ID = sP.pers_personID AND pl.Type = 'WORK') WorkPhone,
          (SELECT Phon_Number FROM Phone p JOIN PhoneLink pl ON pl.PhoneLinkID = p.PhoneLinkID WHERE pl.Person_ID = sP.pers_personID AND pl.Type = 'HOME') HomePhone
   FROM person
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing your table's structure, I'll do some example.

```
select person.id,
  max(case when phone.type='home' then phone.vlaue else 0 end) 'home',
  max(case when phone.type='work' then phone.vlaue else 0 end) 'work'
from person,phone where...
group by person.id
```

Then use this query to join all other tables needed